# « Je m'excuse » ou « excusez-moi » ou « je vous présente mes excuses » ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, politesse

J'ai toujours été convaincu (par mon professeur de français au collège) que la formulation « je m'excuse » était incorrecte et qu'il fallait demander à être excusé : « excusez-moi ».

Une rapide recherche me donne [une explication contraire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/je_m%E2%80%99excuse) sur le Wiktionnaire :

> Une idée reçue fort répandue est que je m’excuse contreviendrait aux
> règles de la grammaire et partant, à celles de la politesse. Les
> adversaires de cette locution affirment qu’on ne dit pas **je m’excuse**,
> puisqu’on n’a pas à s’excuser soi-même, et que d’ailleurs personne ne
> dit *je me pardonne* à la place de *pardonnez-moi*.
>
> C’est oublier que le verbe s’excuser existe depuis fort longtemps au
> sens de « présenter ses excuses » (ex. : *il s’excusa de sa maladresse*)
> et est admis par tous les dictionnaires y compris ceux de l’Académie
> française.
>
> Tout juste peut-on dire que **je m’excuse** fait partie du registre le moins
> formel, et que, en certaines circonstances, si l’on a un doute et
> qu’on craigne de passer pour impoli, mieux vaut s’en tenir à
> « excusez-moi », « veuillez m’excuser », etc.

Du coup, je me demande si je ne devrais pas m'excuser auprès de ceux à qui j'ai pu reprocher de ne pas présenter leurs excuses… :)

Quelqu'un aurait-il une meilleure explication (avec quelques sources un peu plus « officielles » que le Wiktionnaire ;) ) ?

Comment: [L'entrée dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/excuser)

Comment: La SNCF dit : « nous vous prions d'accepter nos excuses ».

Comment: @Benoit Cette variante manquait à ma liste, l'ajoute. Merci !

Comment: Excuser : mettre hors de cause, justifier.

« je m'excuse »  n'est en aucun cas incorrect mais peut parfois être une marque d'arrogance. C'est une question de logique et d'humilité : 

Vous avez été retardé par le bus et vous vous êtes excusé auprès du CPE. Puis vous rentrez en classe et présentez vos excuses que le professeur accepte. Vous venez de vous excuser, mais la politesse demande que vous laissiez (au moins réthoriquement) le professeur être le juge de votre justification.

Comment: En effet "excuser" implique un résultat : vos excuses ont été acceptées. S'excuser est donc légèrement présomptueux, puisqu'on admet comme acquis (ou qu'on prévoit) un résultat qui dépend surtout des autres.

Comment: Réciproquement, la politesse et l'humilité voudrait que le professeur ne vous dise pas "Je vous excuse" (sauf s'il se montre magnanime devant une excuse bidon), mais "Vous êtes excusés", reconnaissant la justesse objective de vos excuses.

Comment: Une jour, mon patron m'en a fait la remarque. Sur le moment j'ai voulu l'etrangler.
Car j'ai toujours eu en tete que "je m'excuse" = "je vous presente mes excuses", je demande pas la permission pour qu'il m'excuse, s'il ne les accepte pas ce n'est plus mon probleme.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Je partage ton sentiment et j'ai moi aussi tenu longtemps *Je m'excuse* comme une « faute de politesse » mineure. Et j'ai moi aussi fait le constat assez récent que l'usage en était largement assez répandu pour cesser de le considérer comme une faute.

Si on voulait faire une sorte de topographie (merci aux nombreux techniciens présents de me corriger, car le terme n'est probablement pas le bon…) des variantes en fonction des registres de langage, on pourrait avoir :

**Langage soutenu :** (par ordre décroissant d'obséquiosité)

- *« Je vous prie de bien vouloir m'excuser. »* (formel, administratif)
- *« Je vous prie d'accepter mes excuses. »* (formel également) *(merci Benoit)*
- *« Je vous présente mes excuses. »* (l'accent est mis sur l'humilité, la subordination voire la soumission)
- *« Je vous prie de m'excuser. »*
- *« Veuillez m'excuser. »*
- *« Toutes mes excuses. »* (presque du langage courant, mais difficile à classer car le sens est légèrement différent)

**Langage courant :** (toujours par ordre décroissant de politesse)

- *« Excusez-moi. »*
- *« Je m'excuse. »*

**Langage familier :** (ce n'était visiblement pas au cœur de la question, je l'ajoute par souci de complétude)

- *« J'm'excuse. »*
- *« Excuse. »*
- *« S'cuse. »*

---

La liste n'est pas exhaustive, mais c'est une bonne base, j'imagine.

Et enfin à titre personnel, j'utilise presque toujours *Excusez-moi* / *Excuse-moi*.

Note : Bien sûr, je suis resté sur les variantes des expressions contenues dans la question initiale, pas sur les autres manières de s'excuser, ne contenant pas le verbe *excuser*, comme *Je suis désolé*, *Pardonne-moi*, etc.

Comment: Logiquement, on ne peut pas s'excuser soi-même, puisqu'on demande l'accord de l'autre. Il faut donc bannir "je m'excuse" de ses automatismes comportementaux.

Comment: @cl-r Oui, c'était précisément le présupposé de départ de Cédric, qu'il pose pour le remettre en question. Si tu ne le partages pas, c'est peut-être la question initiale qu'il fallait commenter ? Voire faire une réponse en ce sens ?

Comment: @cl-r : c'est là mon souci, j'étais convaincu que c'était une faute, et j'ai bien l'impression que ça n'en est plus une...

Comment: @cl-r, le dictionnaire de l'Académie reconnaît cette [acception](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/excuser): (_excuser_, V. pron., Présenter des excuses, exprimer des regrets.) Même si elle conseille de l'éviter à la première personne pour cause d’ambiguïté.  Mais ambiguïté avec quoi ?  Avec le premier sens de _s'excuser_ (alléguer des justifications) qui correspond au premier sens d'_excuser_ (justifier ou s'efforcer de justifier) ?  Entre _excusez-moi_ à l'impératif et _je m'excuse_, je ne suis pas sûr du tout de préférer le premier.

Comment: @CédricJulien - C'en est une en effet, un manque de respect et la signature d'une compréhension amoindrie du français. Si l'on vous dit "excuse[z]-moi", vous pouvez toujours répondre "de quel droit?", "vous décidez à ma place?" et autres réflexions permettant de remettre en place une situation qui vous est désagréable.

Comment: Erratum: lire "je m'excuse" au lieu "d'excuse[z]-moi". @Unfrancophone c'est l'emploi de la première personne du singulier qui me gène, il y a aussi le contexte et l'expression émotionnelle qui peut effacer tout ce qui vient d'être formulé. A l'écrit, "Je vous prie de bien vouloir m'excuser" demeure une formule qui ne peut heurter la personne *offensée* et lui laisse la *grandeur* du pardon.

Comment: @cl-r, si j'en tient aux définitions du dictionnaire de l'Académie, _je vous prie de bien vouloir m'excuser_, c'est une demande à quelqu'un de ne pas tenir rigueur sans nécessairement exprimer des regrets, en particulier si on apporte une justification, _je m'excuse_, c'est un moyen d'exprimer son regret de ce qu'on a fait, sans demande particulière d'indulgence.

Answer (score 7):

La réponse de Romain Valeri me parait très éclairée, j'aimerais cependant revenir sur quelques points.

**Faire quelque chose et le dire**

Revenons d'abord au texte issu du Wiktionnaire. Je conviens que l'usage pronominal du verbe « excuser » a le sens de « présenter des excuses », et donc que « je m'excuse » peut avoir le sens de « je vous présente mes excuses ». Le problème est le suivant : est-ce que dire que l'on présente ses excuses c'est, de fait, présenter ses excuses ? Est-ce que dire que l'on fait quelque chose c'est le faire ? Posée comme cela, la réponse semble être non, évidemment. En ce sens, ni « je m'excuse » ni « je vous présente mes excuses » ne me paraissent correct. Quand quelqu'un dit « je vous présente mes excuses », on aimerait bien savoir ce qu'il a justement comme excuse !

Il existe cependant quelques phrases dont l'énonciation se confond avec l'acte qu'elle décrivent. On parle de phrases *performatives*. Grammaticalement, dans la phrase « je vous salue Marie » on pourrait douter que celui qui la prononce salue réellement Marie, il dit seulement qu'il le fait. Et pourtant le sens est clair, il salue bel et bien Marie par cette phrase.

La question qui se pose alors est d'accepter ou non de donner une valeur performative à « je vous présente mes excuses » ou à « je m'excuse ». Certains le font, je suis plus hésitant. Pour moi c'est le contexte d'énonciation qui confirme la valeur performative d'une phrase. Si je beugle étant enivré « je vous salue Marie », je ne salue pas Marie.
Je réponds donc à la question ainsi :

- « je vous présente mes excuses » est suffisamment humble pour avoir une valeur performative ;
- « je m'excuse » peut être trop vite dit pour être performatif, mais si c'est dit par un enfant de moins de six ans visiblement écrasé par la culpabilité, pourquoi pas.

**Excuser et pardonner**

Les deux verbes *excuser* et *pardonner* ne sont pas des synonymes. Premièrement, la forme pronominale réfléchie *s'excuser* a un sens radicalement différent de *se pardonner* — forme presqu'exclusivement utilisée négativement, comme dans « je ne me pardonnerai jamais… » —, qui exprime un relation vis-à-vis de soi-même.

Ensuite, la forme active — non pronominale — d'*excuser* a un sens proche de *pardonner*, néanmoins leur nature me semble différente. Excuser quelqu'un de quelque chose, c'est soustraire à quelqu'un la responsabilité d'une faute. Pardonner quelque chose à quelqu'un c'est lui signifier que tu ne gardes pas de ressentiment d'une faute, que tu passes outre, mais ça ne remet pas en cause la faute. C'est en général beaucoup plus dur de pardonner car la faute reste entière. Tu peux pardonner à ton grand frère d'avoir déchirer ta peluche préférée quand tu étais enfant, tu ne l'excuses pas pour autant. Inversement, tu peux excuser DSK d'avoir mal tourné en lui trouvant pour cela mille raisons, mais tu peux dans le même temps refuser de lui pardonner. On notera, sans que je sache en donner une interprétation, que dans un cas le fautif est COI et la faute COD alors que dans l'autre cas, c'est précisément l'inverse.

De même, quelqu'un qui donne des excuses ne demande certainement pas pardon. Néanmoins quelqu'un qui présente ses excuses — au sens de dire « je vous présente mes excuses » —, peut en fait ne pas en avoir, auquel cas il demande bel et bien pardon.

**Conclusion**

Personnellement je ne dis jamais « **je m'excuse** » car je trouve que c'est mal habile. Soit on veut être sincère et ce n'est clairement pas une bonne manière de le montrer que de dire « je m'excuse » ; soit on ne veut pas l'être auquel cas il faut être plus subtil au risque d'être insultant. Dans ce dernier cas, on pourra penser à « **faites excuses** » qui est à la fois familier et vieilli, ce qui ne manquera pas de détourner l'attention. Mais je pense que le « je m'excuse » n'est *que* malhabile, ce n'est pas une faute à proprement parler, de par sa valeur performative.

J'utilise le « **excusez-moi** » dans les situations où il n'y a pas faute, par exemple quand je dérange quelqu'un dans ses occupations mais que j'ai de bonnes raisons de le faire. Quand il y a faute, je préfère les formes avec « pardonner », notamment « **pardonnez-moi** » et « **je vous prie de me pardonner** ». Ces formes me paraissent avoir leur place dans le langage courant et elles sont loin d'être obséquieuses, elles montrent simplement une sincérité dans l'excuse. On ne peut demander pardon sans humilité, j'aime autant m'abstenir que de faire semblant de m'excuser.

Par contre, à quelqu'un qui réclame des excuses et à qui on répond « je m'excuse », je lui dirais qu'il l'a bien cherché ! On ne réclame pas des excuses, on les reçoit.

Comment: +1 car je ne connaissais pas les phrases _performatives_. Cela étant dit, dans ce contexte-ci, les véritables excuses suivent généralement le _« je m'excuse »_, qui sert uniquement de préambule.

Comment: @Stamm Sur le sujet des phrases performatives, je te conseille la lecture du très fameux livre de [Searle](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Searle), « Les actes de langage », qui permet de mieux comprendre [cette intéressante théorie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acte_de_langage) en philosophie du langage. Une référence.

Comment: @Lierre De nombreux points intéressants. :-) C'est dommage que le CNRTL soit si court sur l'[étymologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/excuser) d'*excuser*. Les rapports de sens avec *accuser* et *récuser* suggèrent qu'*ex-cuser* soit une construction évoquant "sortir de" + (quelque chose comme la faute, l'opprobre, le déshonneur), mais si quelqu'un en sait plus long, qu'il n'hésite pas !

Answer (score 3):

Je crois qu'on s'égare. Je suis perfectionniste, je n'aime pas les fautes d'orthographe, ni de grammaire, ni de sens, ni d'usage, ni les fautes de frappes (si elles sont trop fréquentes parce qu'on peut se relire quand même) mais (il ne) faut pas pousser mémé dans les orties!

Le langage est une aide à la communication. Il est certes définit par son passé mais il évolue aussi avec l'**usage**. L'USAGE! Les mots ont le sens que nous voulons bien leur donner. Ici, la clarification sur la justesse de la signification du verbe "s'excuser" et des expressions "Je m'excuse" et "Excusez-moi(!)" devait être faite et a été faite dès le premier commentaire! Il y la théorie mais il y a aussi la pratique et il convient de réconcilier les deux. Avec quelques commentaires, on est tombé dans une tentative similaire à celle d'expliquer le paradoxe apparent de la signification de l'expression "Sans doute". Et je n'y tomberai pas moi-même!

*(Je me fiche de l'expression utilisée. "Je m'excuse", "Excusez-moi", "Pardonnez-moi", ... Pourvu qu'elle est sincère! Souvent, et fort heureusement, les mots sont inutiles. Si je vois la personne en faute ou qui a fait une erreur regretter son acte ou qu'un mal-être l'envahit, cela me suffit pour lui pardonner sur-le-champ. Encore une belle expression "sur-le-champ"!)*

*(Vous imaginez! Vous êtes assis au restaurant et une dame souhaite passer derrière votre siège mais l'espace est trop étroit.*

*- "Excusez-moi monsieur mais je voudrais passer s'il vous plaît."*

*- "Non, madame. Je ne vous excuse pas. Pour qui vous prenez-vous pour exiger quoi que ce soit de moi? Je ne suis pas votre chien! Maintenant, laissez-moi! Je souhaiterais dîner en paix.)*

Comment: Bienvenue sur French.SX ! Le but du jeu est de répondre à des questions. Ici, la question porte sur la sémantique précise de « s’excuser », les réponses s’y intéressent donc. Si ta réponse apporte des éléments valides (je comprends que tu estimes ces distinctions inutiles, particulièrement au quotidien), il me semble qu’une partie importante de son contenu n’aide pas ceux qui s’intéressent à la question ou s’y intéresseront à l’avenir. D’ailleurs, les réponses se veulent essentiellement indépendantes les unes des autres. Ce sont les *commentaires* qui permettent de discuter d’une réponse.

Comment: Oui, et en plus les orties ça pique.

Answer (score 2):

### Mon grain de sel

La réponse faite par Romain VALERI me semble faire le tour du sujet…
Je voulais également faire un petit bravo @cl-r, pour avoir été le seul à utiliser le nom *impératif* sur cette page, après plus de 6 mois.

#### Mon point de vue

Pour ma part, je pense qu'utiliser l'impératif (que l'on utilise pour donner des ordres comme : *Je vous ordonne de m'excuser*) et tout aussi mal venu que de s'excuser soi-même (je ne vous demande pas votre avis : *je m'excuse*).

L'impératif s'exprime également à l'aide d'un point d'exclamation.

> Excuse me!

C'est tout aussi moche en anglais!

(Google me dit que *I apologize* est la traduction de *Je m'excuse* ???)

Nota: Pour moi, on peut tout aussi bien l'écrire *je messcuze* : la faute de français ne l'emportera pas sur la faute diplomatique (au contraire, aurait tendance à l'excuser, voire plus bas).

#### Peut mieux faire?

Non en fait, le seule moyen de se faire pardonner, c'est bien ***d'obtenir le pardon de la personne offensée !***
En fait, si ***Veuillez m'excuser !*** semble plus sympathique, le verbe *vouloir* reste pratiqué à l'impératif : *je vous ordonne de vouloir m'excuser*… Je suis d'accord, c'est curieux mais c'est un *effet de bord de l'impératif*.

> I beg your pardon. Je vous demande pardon.

Est une formule que je qualifierai d'*acceptable*.
Car elle n'impose rien mais place le fautif en position de demandeur et relate l'état de la situation.

Mieux, quoique…

> Je vous prie de m'excuser.

Comme précédemment, mais là, la demande devient une *prière*.

A partir de là, on commence à devenir pompeux (flatteur, insidieux, suspect). Au delà de cette forme de respect, je commence à me méfier!

> Oserai-je l'affront de solliciter votre immense bienveillance afin d'accepter de bien vouloir m'accorder votre pardon ?

#### Changement de cap

> Je vous présente mes (plus plates) excuses.

J'aime bien cette formule car elle peut être décorée en fonction des besoins (de cas en cas), car bien souvent, ces excuses sont qualifiables: plates, empressés, insistantes, désolées, voire tristes et Jean Noublie.

#### Finalité

Dans quel but ? réconciliation, regain de confiance, nouveau départ ou simple convenance sociale ?

En écrivant ceci, j'ai cherché des exemples dans mes souvenirs et ai réalisé que la formule dépend

- du type de destinataire (employeur, chef, conjoint, voisin, quidam ou policier).
- de l'importance que l'on y accorde.
- du respect que l'on accorde à l'autre (et à soi-même, mais c'est un autre sujet).
- du niveau d'éducation (perso, je préfère un cuistre qui me demande *j'm'esscuze?* qu'un érudit qui m'ordonne  *veuillez m'excuser !!*… l'intonation joue également un p%*#ç% de rôle !)

Sans oublier, parlant de finalité, qu'on peut parfois mieux s'en sortir avec une boite de cigares, une bonne bouteille ou des fleurs !

Nota: Question de personnalité : Je n'aime pas trop les personnes, ne sachant pas reconnaître leur torts, qui ne demandent jamais pardon, mais je n'aime pas beaucoup plus ceux qui s'excusent sans arrêt (dans les faits, ils ont le même problème) :

> – Aaah et cessez de vous excuser ainsi, c'est agaçant à la fin !
>
> – Je sais, je vous demande pardon : c'est plus fort que moi… Désolé !

Voilà, c'est tout pour aujourd'hui.

Comment: Réponse très nourrie et pleine de bon sens. Simple remarque au sujet de l'impératif : il n'est pas réservé à l'expression des ordres, il a bien d'autres emplois, parmi lesquels le conseil ou la prière, qui me semblent parfaitement adaptés à notre cas présent. *Excusez-moi* étant alors l'exacte traduction de *Je vous prie de m'excuser.*

Comment: Hmmm non, je ne crois pas: l'impératif ne sert effectivement pas `qu'à` donner des ordres, mais dans les autres cas, le **verbe** doit faire référence à soi-même ou servir à signifier un état de chose ou un voeux: `Soyez heureux!` (Quoiqu'en y réflechissant, il s'agit bien d'un ordre;). `Excusez-moi!` n'est, selon moi, pas interprétable autrement que `je vous ordonne de m'excuser`. Cela dit, les fautes-courantes-qui-deviennent- `règle` son foison, en français. (Comme `ça pleut` ou `bonjour` après 17h... J'aime souhaiter le bon jour en partant, par un `bonjour` accompagnant la poignée de main;)

Comment: Prends un autre exemple : *Aidez-moi!* est-il (intonation mise à part) suppliant ou autoritaire ? Il me semble que le mode impératif ne suggère pas toujours l'ordre ou l'autorité, ce n'est qu'un de ses usages possibles. Quand à la question de la pertinence (ou non) d'utiliser en français le même mode pour des besoins aussi différents, c'est une autre question... (quoique très intéressante!)

Answer (score -1):

Assez, d'accord avec la dernière intervention.

Toutefois, et malgré les études éclairantes des linguistes / grammairiens, concernant l'usage, je dirais que l'expression  « je m'excuse » est une faute comportementale.  Peut être n'est-ce pas correct du point de vue de la langue française, peut être que si. Mais c'est surtout une incorrection du point de vue du comportement ou de la politesse.
Je présente des excuses à quelqu'un : il n'est pas obligé de les accepter. Donc je ne peux pas lui donner l'ordre de les accepter. « Excusez-moi », ou « je m'excuse » ... il n'y a pas de différences. Peut-être peut-on dire « **Je vous prie de bien vouloir accepter mes excuses** », « **Je vous présente mes excuses** » ou « **Je vous prie de bien vouloir excuser**  ».

Dans tous les cas je vous remercie de cet échange ; personnellement, je vais rester sur la formule « Je vous prie de bien vouloir accepter mes excuses » en tant que trmes à utiliser à l'adresse de personnes telles que mon supérieur, cela me semble la moins risqué.