# « Excusez-moi » vis-à-vis de « Pardon »

Tags: oral

Je ne sais pas toujours quand utiliser les deux expressions : « Excusez-moi » ou « Pardon ». Dans une conversation, si je ne comprends pas, est-ce je peux dire « Pardon, plus lentement, s'il vous plaît ? » ?  Autrement dit, je ne dis « Pardon » que quand je suis en métro ou après avoir bousculé quelqu'un. (Or, en anglais, I use "*Pardon*" only when I am try to ask someone to yield/give way on public transit or when I bump into someone by accident. Or I can also use it to mean: "sorry, can you please speak slower"?).  Merci beaucoup pour votre aide!

Comment: Bienvenue sur Fr.se. Bonne question que les anglophones peuvent se poser, bien que le *pardon* anglais vienne du français, le sens anglais a perdu la notion de demande d'excuse à une offense grave qu'il a gardé en français.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le sens premier de **pardon** (déverbal de pardonner, du latin *perdonare*), apparu au 12<sup>e</sup> siècle était religieux : le pardon était la remise de peine pour ses péchés accordée par l'église (on disait aussi l'« indulgence »). Le mot est entré dans le domaine laïque avec un sens atténué au 16<sup>e</sup> siècle  dans la formule de politesse « Je vous demande pardon ».
L'interjection raccourcie « Pardon ! » est devenue au 20<sup>e</sup> siècle une exclamation populaire emphatique synonyme de « Excusez-moi ! ».
Le mot était passé dans la langue anglaise au 15<sup>e</sup> siècle dans son sens religieux, a été employé dès le 16<sup>e</sup> siècle, dans l'expression *I beg your pardon* pour exprimer de simples excuses, comme en France, mais il semblerait (source l'OED) que l'interjection raccourcie en « *pardon* » ait été employée dès le 19<sup>e</sup> siècle en anglais, avant la France. Y a-t-il eu là, retour vers la France et, le simple « pardon » pour signifier « excusez-moi » serait-il un de ces mots voyageurs qui ont fait des allers retours de chaque côté de la Manche ?

L'emploi de « pardon » ou d’« excusez-moi » dépend fortement des individus et des circonstances. 
Quand je veux qu'on me laisse passer, surtout dans le métro et que je ne veux pas rater ma station, je dirai plus volontiers « pardon », probablement parce que c'est plus court, et si je veux passer c'est que je suis pressé et que l'autre n'avait qu'à pas se mettre sur mon chemin.
Quand je bouscule quelqu'un, je dirai plus volontiers « Excusez-moi », probablement parce que je suis en tort, et que j'aurais dû faire attention. Peut-être que « Excusez-moi » sonne comme plus poli ?
Pour attirer l'attention de quelqu'un, et que de ce fait je le dérange, par exemple parce que je veux demander mon chemin dans un lieu que je ne connais pas, je dirai « Bonjour, excusez moi », jamais « pardon ».

Et il arrive assez souvent d'entendre « Pardon, excusez-moi », et à noter aussi l'ironique « Excusez-moi si je vous demande pardon ».

Il sera intéressant de poursuivre par la lecture de cette question et de ses réponses : [« Je m'excuse » ou « excusez-moi » ou « je vous présente mes excuses » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2812/358)

<sup>Références étymologiques issues du *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Pour moi on *demande* **pardon** càd que l'on regrette sincèrement ce que l'on a fait et qu'on ne le refera plus. Demander pardon implique donc avoir commis une faute grave ou un fait trés répréhensible.

*Je te demande pardon de t'avoir volé de l'argent.*

D'autre part, **Excusez-moi** est une simple formule de politesse sollicitant le pardon de l'auditeur. Cette expression est plus largement utilisée *pour demander à quelqu’un de répéter*, *pour quitter une conversation*, *pour appeler le serveur*, ou plus simplement *présenter ses excuses*.

*Je me suis trompé, veuillez m'excuser.*

Comment: On utilise aussi « pardon » en français pour présenter ses excuses. D'ailleurs souvent accompagné de « excusez-moi ».

Comment: Tu as raison sur le fait que *pardon* a généralement un sens plus fort ou plus appuyé, par rapport à *excusez-moi* qui est plus léger. Attention toutefois à ne pas le présenter comme un fait aussi tranché : il arrive aussi que le premier soit utilisé au sens léger. On l'entend parfois répété plusieurs fois sur un ton très neutre, provenant de quelqu'un se frayant un chemin dans la foule par exemple.

Comment: Merci ! Alors, c'est étrange utiliser pardon quand on voudrait naviguer à travers une foule dans le métro, par exemple ? Ce serait meilleur dire excusez-moi ? (J'ai peur que j'aie exprimé des regrettes sincères quand j'en n'aie pas du tout !)

Comment: Non, aucun problème, rassure-toi. Les deux formes peuvent être employées dans ce contexte, sans paraître inutilement sophistiquées ou solennelles.

Comment: Je m'étonne de l'absence de l'aberration qu'est "je m'excuse" dans ce sujet ;p

Comment: @Kilazur Oui, en effet, d'autres se sont fait la même réflexion que toi, voir [le lien](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/je-mexcuse-ou-excusez-moi-ou-je-vous-presente-mes-excuses) cité par Laure.

Comment: Pour résumer, je dirais que "pardon" est plus solennel, mais aussi plus court. Donc si vous êtes pressé, ne perdez pas de temps à dire "excusez-moi" car vous allez rater le train !

Answer (score 0):

To add to what others have said:  It depends on the context and the exact phrase, not just which verb you use.

*Pardonnez-moi* can be as serious as *forgive me* (for which you recognize fault) or as lightweight as *excuse me* (for which you have not necessarily done anything yet, let alone anything wrong).

*Demander pardon* is pretty serious and definitely recognizes fault.  It is to *ask for forgiveness*.  Similarly, *demander des excuses* and *presenter ses excuses* are serious: *ask someone to apologize* and *apologize*, respectively.

Just *Pardon* (possibly repeated), when trying to make your way through a crowd, is similar to *pardon me* or *excuse me* (or even just *pardon*) in English.

There is not really a one-to-one relationship between either *pardonner* or *s'excuser* and either *to pardon* or *to excuse oneself*.